# How are `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts` used for client authentication?

Tags: ssh, authentication

SSH The Definitive Guide says

> OpenSSH maintains a single database serving both server authentication and client
>   authentication. It is the union of the system’s known_hosts file (`/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`), together with the user’s `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on either the source machine
>   (for server authentication) or the target machine (for **client authentication**).

How are `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and  `~/.ssh/known_hosts` used for client authentication?

According to https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20710/, 
I think `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and  `~/.ssh/known_hosts` are for server authentication only, and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is for user authentication only.

Does "client authentication" mean the same as "user authentication"?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have the public key of the server you're about to connect to, you can add it to ~/.ssh/known_hosts on the client manually.

Comment: That is for server authentication. What is "client authentication" here?

Comment: The same, but used by server to directly reject untrusted client host. After passing the client authentication, that client still need to pass user authentication. Used in case like "I don't want anyone but only computers of my company to connect, no matter how much user password or user private key or any type of user credentials they are holding".

Comment: Does "client authentication" mean the same as "user authentication"?

How are /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts and ~/.ssh/known_hosts used for client authentication?

Comment: **You are correct** and the book apparently isn't definitive. Server auth (by the client) uses known_hosts at the client. Client/user auth (by the server) uses authorized_keys at the server _if_ you use publickey, but other kinds of client/user auth (such as password) do not. SSH (like rsh and telnet) was designed for a human connecting to a timesharing system so it treats client and user as the same thing; the protocol messages are named SSH_MSG_USERAUTH_various (see RFC 4252) but have the effect of authenticating the client process.

Answer (score -1):

in ~/.ssh you have several files (known_hosts, authorized_keys, id_rsa & id_rsa.pub).

If on machine A you want to login to machine B as same user without password you can (even if it's not recommended) copy the content of Machine A id_rsa.pub in Machine B ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. That's user authentication.

The first time you want to login to Machine B, Machine A will request you to trust it then it will put the public key of Machine B in ~/.ssh/known_hosts. That is client authentication the Machine A ssh process is client to Machine B sshd service.

Comment: It is not restricted to the same user, and I don't see why "it is not recommended".